# SAS - Analysis on 'Fraud' Account/Routing numbers via RDIs (bad checks)

Tags: sas, finance, banking, fraud-prevention

So I am new to SAS and the business world and am having a terrible time with a task that I am doing.

**Brief:** I have a data set *RDI_HIST* which shows all RDIs by account/routing # within ~6 Months. There are ~250,000 transactions in the data set, some of which are the same customer (same acct/routing #).

I was told to run an analysis on this data, but first I am not sure if I have it sorted/grouped to do so (see table).

```
+------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| RDI_RT_TRAN_CODE | RDI_ACCT_NO | RDI_AMOUNT | RDI_TOTAL | COUNT |
+------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------+
|              518 |           0 | 3117.00    | 3777.5    |     3 |
|              518 |           0 | 170.00     | 3777.5    |     3 |
|              518 |           0 | 490.50     | 3777.5    |     3 |
|         26013673 |           0 | 755.63     | 755.63    |     1 |
|         31100225 |           0 | 31.40      | 31.4      |     1 |
|         41001039 |           0 | 143.10     | 143.1     |     1 |
|         41202443 |           0 | 32.38      | 32.38     |     1 |
|         41203824 |           0 | 63.31      | 63.31     |     1 |
|         41207341 |           0 | 43.00      | 375.87    |     4 |
|         41207341 |           0 | 184.87     | 375.87    |     4 |
|         41207341 |           0 | 15.00      | 375.87    |     4 |
|         41207341 |           0 | 133.00     | 375.87    |     4 |
|         41208719 |           0 | 247.57     | 247.57    |     1 |
|         41215621 |           0 | 220.00     | 630       |     4 |
|         41215621 |           0 | 250.00     | 630       |     4 |
|         41215621 |           0 | 60.00      | 630       |     4 |
|         41215621 |           0 | 100.00     | 630       |     4 |
|         43301601 |           0 | 1999.70    | 2407.16   |     3 |
|         43301601 |           0 | 330.18     | 2407.16   |     3 |
|         43301601 |           0 | 77.28      | 2407.16   |     3 |
|         43306910 |           0 | 1200.00    | 1200      |     1 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 1312.65    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 1352.37    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 2939.98    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 1500.00    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 1309.10    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         43313259 |           0 | 1438.42    | 9852.52   |     6 |
|         44103976 |           0 | 126.00     | 126       |     1 |
+------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

For the Analysis, I'm really not sure where to start. The main objective is to create a piece of code that pulls in the customers that have several RDIs (bad checks) and add them to a blacklist on a weekly basis. What the parameters are for that list, I am not sure yet, so I am just trying to come up with some decent statistics.

I will be sure to pay it forward, if anyone is able to provide some help. I will be here to answer any questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with proc means.
Assuming that RDI_ACCT_NO is the customer ID you could group by that:

```
proc means data=RDI_HIST;
var RDI_RT_TRAN_CODE RDI_AMOUNT RDI_TOTAL;
by RDI_ACCT_NO;
run;
```

This will quickly give you summary statistics for the selected variables by your customer ID.

Also, I'd strongly suggest looking at SAS support communities. Stackoverflow is great but SAS has a large community of programmers ready to help SAS people too.

Comment: Agreed, especially when you're not really asking a technical question but need more methodology or direction which are not valid on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Start by brute force. First get the distribution of your RDI and then design a cutoff.

Assuming your data is called `have` and variable names are as shown then something like the following is useful.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
table rdi_account_no / out=rdi_counts;
run;

proc rank data=rdi_counts groups=100 out=rdi_counts_ranked;
var count;
ranks rank_count;
run;

proc freq data=rdi_counts_ranked;
table rank_count;
run;
```

You'll want to examine the distribution of the last proc freq which is essentially a distribution of the # of accounts. Ie if you look at the 90th percentile it tells you how many accounts fall into that group. You can also take a look at the CDF in PROC UNIVARIATE.

```
proc univariate data=rdi_counts_ranked;
histogram rank_count;
cdf rank_count;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate this.